# SparkContext parallelize lazy behavior - unexplained

Tags: scala, apache-spark

According to Spark source code comments.

SparkContext.scala has

```
  /** Distribute a local Scala collection to form an RDD.
   *
   * @note Parallelize acts lazily. If `seq` is a mutable collection and is altered after the call
   * to parallelize and before the first action on the RDD, the resultant RDD will reflect the
   * modified collection. Pass a copy of the argument to avoid this.
   * @note avoid using `parallelize(Seq())` to create an empty `RDD`. Consider `emptyRDD` for an
   * RDD with no partitions, or `parallelize(Seq[T]())` for an RDD of `T` with empty partitions.
   */
```

So, I thought I'd do a simple test.

```
scala> var c = List("a0", "b0", "c0", "d0", "e0", "f0", "g0")
c: List[String] = List(a0, b0, c0, d0, e0, f0, g0)

scala> var crdd = sc.parallelize(c)
crdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:26

scala> c = List("x1", "y1")
c: List[String] = List(x1, y1)

scala> crdd.foreach(println)
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 8]d0
a0
b0
e0
f0
g0
c0

scala>
```

I was expecting `crdd.foreach(println)` to output "`x1`" and "`y1`", based on the lazy behavior of `parallelize`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't modify `c` at all. You re-assigned it to a new List.

Besides that point,

> If `seq` is a mutable collection

Scala's `List` is not a mutable collection

> and is altered after the call to parallelize and before the first action on the RDD

Well, see, you didn't really alter the list.

---

Here's a proper example of the documented behavior.

```
scala> val c = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer(1, 2, 3)
c: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3)

scala> val cRDD = sc.parallelize(c)
cRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at parallelize at <console>:29

scala> c.append(4)

scala> c
res7: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> cRDD.collect()
res8: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: That explains. Thanks.